# Is take operator ask for an unbounded amount of elements?

Tags: java, project-reactor

```
Flux.just("a", "b", "c", "d")
        .log(null, Level.INFO, true) // line 20
        .take(3)
        .subscribe();
```

Some of the output:

```
12:56:21 [main] INFO  - | request(unbounded)    Flux.log(App.java:20)
```

Question:

Why `take` ask for an unbounded amount of elements instead of only `2` from `flatMap`?

Answer (score 0):

take works by requesting an unbounded amount and cancelling upon having received enough elements

Comment: That may cause unnessesery proccessing of extra elements. Then why reactor took this decision?